# How to move substrings around with in a string python 3

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace, slice

Obviosuly I've gotten to the point where I'm at my ends with python and need prespective on what to do about a large string in which everything is out of order.

```
"KMEM AMD01 012200Z 0122/0217 012259Z OVC009  11/2SM -DZ BR 36008KT TEMPO 0122/0202 OVC004  3SM -DZ BR FM020200 OVC012  02009KT TEMPO 0202/0205 OVC007  4SM -DZ BR FM020500 OVC012  5SM BR02009KT FM020900 BKN009  5SM -DZ BR 02009KT FM021300 OVC012  02005KT FM021600 OVC018  VRB03 ="
```

I have seperated it out to how its supposed to look

```
KMEM 122259Z 1222/1217 OVC009 11/2SM -DZ BR 36008KT 
      TEMPO 0122/0202 OVC004  3SM -DZ BR 
    FM020200 OVC012  02009KT 
      TEMPO 0202/0205 OVC007  4SM -DZ BR 
    FM020500 OVC012  5SM BR 02009KT 
    FM020900 BKN009  5SM -DZ BR 02009KT 
    FM021300 OVC012 02005KT 
    FM021600 OVC018  VRB03KT =
```

I need some ideas not on how to move some of the substrings in the original string

Its supposed to look something like this

```
KMEM 122259Z 1223/1217 36008KT 11/2SM -DZ BR OVC009  
      TEMPO 0122/0202 3SM -DZ BR OVC004   
    FM020200 02009KT OVC012  
      TEMPO 0202/0205 4SM -DZ BR OVC007 
    FM020500 02009KT 5SM BR 
    FM020900 02009KT 5SM -DZ BR BKN009  
    FM021300 02005KT OVC012  
    FM021600 VRB03KT OVC018 =
```

Everything has a specific order {winds, visibility, present weather, clouds,}

For example the first line

```
OVC009 11/2SM -DZ BR 36008KT
```

Is supposed to be

```
36008KT 11/2SM -DZ BR OVC009
```

Comment: Is this your data source: https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data

Comment: no I string manipulated to but it is the tafs https://www.aviationweather.gov/taf

Comment: It isn't clear how you are creating your primary string.  Can you provide more details on how this string is created?